# What is the SSJS equivalent to RaiseError in AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Is there an AMPScript's RaiseError function equivalent in SSJS in Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - SSJS also has a ['RaiseError()' function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityRaiseError.htm):

Sample:

```
<script runat="server">     
     var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
     var newObject = Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(CreateRequest,StatusAndRequestID,Options);
     var status = StatusAndRequestID[0];
     var requestID = StatusAndRequestID[1];     if(Result != "OK") {
         Platform.Function.RaiseError("Create failed. Ensure your call successfully invoked the Create method.",false,"statusCode","3");
     }
</script>
```

Comment: You can also do a `try/catch` in SSJS.

Comment: Hi Gortonington/Adam, when i use SSJS: do I have to do the `Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5")`command in order to use `Write("<br>" + Stringify(e))` or `RaiseError(..)`? Or is it possible to just include a prefix like `Platform.Function.Write(..)`? I am uncertain how much of a performance aspect it is to load the Core 1.1.5 lib. Therefore i would like to get more insight in that.